# Output of System.out.println( m[1]+` ´+m[ 2])

Tags: java, arrays, char

```
int m[ ]= {2,4,6,8}
System.out.println( m[1]+' '+m[2])
```

Why is the output 42 in this case?

Comment: Because `' '` is a char (which is treated as a number). Try using `" "` instead of `' '`.

Comment: Cause your adding (int) 4 to a (char)6 = 4 + 38 = 42

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.